# Import into database (MySQL), skip all duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a basic command

```
mysql -u root -p adsf21 < datadump.dump
```

It's about 20 million records, so it's taking some time.  I did it over SSH and my network disconnected.  I need to re-import it but since ~10 million records were already imported, I don't want to redo all of the work I did.

Is there any way to add a parameter to disallow any duplicates from being entered?

Comment: if it's SSH to linux, use Screen and just re-import, if you'll get dc'd it wont stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sql command for skipping duplicate is `insert ignore`, but I'm afraid your script is not going to take much less time because every insert query has to be executed against the db.

Moreover you probably need to modify your datadump.dump. I don't know how you created it, but in any case this operation is going to take very long as well!

If you simply decode to repeat the operation use **screen**, and there will be no matter if you lose connection!